# Splitting grouped pandas dataframe by time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I need to split my dataset into two splits: 80% and 20%.

My dataset looks like this:

```
PersonID    Timestamp   Foo1    Foo2    Foo3    Label
1   1626184812  6   5   2   1
2   616243602   8   5   2   1
2   634551342   4   8   3   1
2   1531905378  3   8   8   1
3   616243602   10  7   8   2
3   634551342   7   5   8   2
4   1626184812  7   9   1   2
4   616243602   5   7   9   1
4   634551342   9   1   6   2
4   1531905378  3   3   3   1
4   768303369   6   1   7   2
5   1626184812  5   7   8   2
5   616243602   6   2   6   1
6   1280851467  3   2   2   2
7   1626184812  10  1   10  1
7   616243602   6   3   6   2
7   1531905378  9   5   7   2
7   634551342   3   7   9   1
8   616243602   8   7   4   2
8   634551342   2   2   4   1
```

(Note, you should be able to use `pd.read_clipboard()` [to get this data into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).)

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- Split this dataset into an 80/20 split (training, testing)
- The dataset should be mostly organized by `Timestamp`, meaning, the *older* data should be in training, and the *newer* data should be in testing
- **Additionally, a single Person should not be split between training and testing. For example, all of the samples for a given PersonID must be in one set or the other!**

The first two points are accomplished in the minimal example below. The third point is what I am having trouble with. For example, using [`sklearn's train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

Minimal example below:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Normal split
x = pd.read_clipboard()
train, test = train_test_split(x, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.20, random_state=8)

# Organizing it by time
x = pd.read_clipboard()
x = x.sort_values(by='Timestamp')
train, test = train_test_split(x, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.20, random_state=8)
```

I am struggling to figure out how to group the dataframe so that one person is not split across train and test. For example, in above, each `PersonID` in the `test` dataframe *also* appears in the `train` dataframe. How can I keep the proportions *about* equal while ensuring that PersonID is not split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two conditions are a bit hard to put together in a rigorous way: older timestamps in train vs single PersonID either train or test but not both. here are two ideas.

For the older timestamps in train, ***probably not the most rigorous solution***, but you can try to get the `max` (or the `min` or the `mean` up to you) of timestamp per personID and the `count`, then `sort_values` the max to `cumsum` the count. Split train-test with the `max` of the `cumsum` multiply by your 80%.

```
# calculate the cumsum of count
s = (
    x.groupby('PersonID')
     ['Timestamp'].agg(['max','count'])
     .sort_values('max')
     ['count'].cumsum()
)
s = s<s.max()*0.8 # get boolean mask for train personID
```

and then you get

```
train = x.loc[x['PersonID'].isin(s[s].index)]
print(train)
#     PersonID   Timestamp  Foo1  Foo2  Foo3  Label
# 0          1  1626184812     6     5     2      1
# 1          2   616243602     8     5     2      1
# 2          2   634551342     4     8     3      1
# 3          2  1531905378     3     8     8      1
# 4          3   616243602    10     7     8      2
# 5          3   634551342     7     5     8      2
# 6          4  1626184812     7     9     1      2
# 7          4   616243602     5     7     9      1
# 8          4   634551342     9     1     6      2
# 9          4  1531905378     3     3     3      1
# 10         4   768303369     6     1     7      2
# 13         6  1280851467     3     2     2      2
# 18         8   616243602     8     7     4      2
# 19         8   634551342     2     2     4      1


test = x.loc[x['PersonID'].isin(s[~s].index)]
print(test)
#     PersonID   Timestamp  Foo1  Foo2  Foo3  Label
# 11         5  1626184812     5     7     8      2
# 12         5   616243602     6     2     6      1
# 14         7  1626184812    10     1    10      1
# 15         7   616243602     6     3     6      2
# 16         7  1531905378     9     5     7      2
# 17         7   634551342     3     7     9      1
```

The other option is to use [sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html#sklearn-model-selection-groupshufflesplit) like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, train_size=.8, random_state=42)

for train_idx, test_idx in gss.split(x.index, groups=x['PersonID']):
     print("TRAIN ID:", x.loc[train_idx,'PersonID'].unique(), 
           ", Timestamp:", x.loc[train_idx,'Timestamp'].mean(),)
     print("TEST ID:", x.loc[test_idx,'PersonID'].unique(), 
           ", Timestamp:", x.loc[test_idx,'Timestamp'].mean())
# TRAIN ID: [1 3 4 5 7 8] , Timestamp: 997267296.9375
# TEST ID: [2 6] , Timestamp: 1015887947.25
```

and increase the parameter `n_splits` and keep the the split that gives the smallest mean for the train or highest for the test.